# How do I find the maximum value in a column that has an apostrophe

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have numbers with apostrophes and when I ask to find the maximum value in a column, =max(B3:B29), it gives me an answer of 0 because these numbers have an apostrophe after them (example: 54.44'). Can someone tell me how to return an actual number from these columns? Thank you

Comment: Do all the numbers have this?

Comment: Remove the apostrophe first?

Comment: Use this formula `=MAX(INDEX(--SUBSTITUTE(B3:B29,"'",""),))`

Comment: The real answer here is: fix your data.  As they are numbers, store them as numbers.  If you need to display a `'` use Formatting.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an array formula that will remove the rightmost character. Type this formula and when done instead of hitting 'enter' hit 'ctrl-shift-enter' to create an array formula:

```
=max(value(left(B3:B23, len(B3:B29) - 1)))
```